# I'm trying to learn about subqueries in Google Analytics and I keep getting errors in this section. Barely know what a syntax is

Tags: sql, subquery

```
SELECT
    station_id,
    name,
    number_of_rides AS number_of_rides_starting_at_station 
FROM
    (SELECT 
         start_station_id,
         COUNT(*) number_of_rides
     FROM
         bigquery-public-data.new_york_citibike.citibike_stations
     GROUP BY 
         start_station_id) AS sation_num_trips
INNER JOIN 
    bigquery-public-data.new_york_citibike.citibike_stations ON station_id = start_station_id
ORDER BY 
    num_of_rides DESC
```

I keep getting an error:

> Syntax error: Expected ")" but got "(" at [10:8]"

WTF DOES THAT EVEN MEAN??!??!!??!!

I keep switching it around but can't get this thing to work. Really can't understand why there are so many errors when I am following the videos on Google exactly.

I've cheated in all my programming classes in college by copying others code. No I guess copying won't work with Google

Comment: Please format your code with a ```code``` text format.

Answer (score 0):

There are some mistakes with your query, I'm going to listed them:

1. You´re trying to call the field start_station_id that doesn't exists in the table bigquery-public-data.new_york_citibike.citibike_stations.
2. In the order by you´re calling the field num_of_rides , but in your subquery you called it number_of_rides, so that give you an error.

I change those two parts of your query , and it returns results, I hope that this is  what you're locking for.

```
SELECT station_id, name, number_of_rides AS number_of_rides_starting_at_station    
FROM    
    (SELECT station_id station_id1, COUNT(*) number_of_rides 
    FROM bigquery-public-data.new_york_citibike.citibike_stations 
    GROUP BY station_id)    
AS sation_num_trips 
INNER JOIN bigquery-public-data.new_york_citibike.citibike_stations 
ON station_id = station_id1 
ORDER BY number_of_rides DESC;
```